# select2 multiple select changing style of selected values

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am looking to try and format or change the style of the selected items from a select2 selection. That is when you use select2 on multiple selections (dropdown select option field), the options you choose jump into a multiple selection box with a little x on them to remove if you choose.

I am trying to format these chosen selections (see image) so that the page looks neater. Trying to make the font smaller and the background color a different color, struggling... 
[image: Selected options]

Can anyone assist in this regard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the given file css files with respect to the given file https://github.com/select2/select2-bootstrap-theme/blob/master/docs/css/select2-bootstrap.css

Comment: you are right, this need to be done by overriding the css, for example using this: `.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice{color:red;}`

Comment: Thank you, sorted me out :)

Answer (score 2):

here is some useful css selectors with styles for that:

```
.select2-selection__choice{
    margin-top: 0px!important;
    padding-right: 5px!important;
    padding-left: 5px!important;
    background-color: transparent!important;
    border:none!important;
    border-radius: 4px!important;
    background-color: rgba(0, 139, 139, 0.09) !important;
}

.select2-selection__choice__remove{
    border: none!important;
    border-radius: 0!important;
    padding: 0 2px!important;
}

.select2-selection__choice__remove:hover{
    background-color: transparent!important;
    color: #ef5454 !important;
}
```